# Can I have a date+timestamp column in sql server db update automatically on insert or update?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, adventureworks

I want to have a column in my tables called ModifiedDate that automatically updates when a row is inserted or updated. Can this be done without writing code in the c# clients that use the db?

Copying a similar column in the AdventureWorks2008R2 sample database, I tried using a datetime2 data type + specifying the column Default Value as "(getdate())" but that doesn't work for me

Is there a way to do this at the database level so I'm not relying on the client app coders to set the field in their c# app ?

Answer (score 1):

How about using default values?
During insert , if you are not providing any value, the column will be updated with the provided default value.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
OrderDate date DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Comment: Thats what I tried to do by setting the column's Default Value to "(getdate())" but that doesn't work for me - should it be that simple or have I missed a step in setting that up?

Comment: @GaryBarrett I am not sure, how you are using GETDATE() method in your Query, I am updating my answerwith one example code from W3schools to check your syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Look up the SQL documentation (copy paste is not going to make you smarter) - the keyword you look for is TRIGGER.A trigger can react to inserts / updates / deeltes and update the data inserted / updated.